# How to calculate launch configuration properties?

Tags: jboss

in Eclipse Jboss 7.1 VM arguments
My RAM 8GB
vm arguments have a this like statements ;
 
-server -Xms**64**m 
 
-Xmx**512**m 
 
-XX:MaxPermSize=**1024**m
how to calculate this bold numbers?

**

> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because your server used up all of its available memory (in your case, **512mb**). You can increase **Xmx** param, which sets the maximum amount of memory your server can use.

OutOfMemoryError can happen because of insufficient memory assignment, or memory leaks (objects that java's garbage collector can't delete, despite not being needed).

There is no magic rule to calculate those params, they depend on what you are deploying to jboss, how much concurrent users, etc, etc, etc.

You can try increasing Xmx param, and check with jvisualvm the memory usage, see how it behaves..